# Why some mathematicians axiomatized number sets?

Tags: axioms, natural-numbers

There was sense of natural numbers before Peano. Likewise why did Peona axiomatized Natural Numbers? Or later, why some mathematicians did axiomatize the Real Numbers or Complex Numbers? And before these axioms couldn't people do calculations, or what was the necessity for axioms? What triggered them?

Thanks from now.

Comment: Well, mathematicians like to be very precise about things when possible. Geometry also existed long before Euclid.  If you want to be able to prove some statements like the intermediate value theorem without hand-waving, you have to assume certain things about the real numbers.  So it's a good idea to axiomatize.  I do think it's fully possible to do great mathematics without such formalization, as was done before the late 19th century or so.  But they could not definitively answer many questions, and we can with modern rigor.

Comment: Oh, I see thank you.

Comment: If you want a light-hearted exposition of how math came to be formalized, you should read [Logicomix](https://www.amazon.com/Logicomix-search-truth-Apostolos-Doxiadis/dp/1596914521).

Comment: It has very little to do with "can we do calculations?"  It's more "Does this set actually exist?" and therefore "Does this calculation make any sense?"  In the late 19th century and early 20th century, a lot of seemingly innocent assumptions we were making turned out to be inconsistent, and the popular result was to formalize everything.  Even now, while rare, you will have some professional mathematicians/logicians deny the existence of the set of real numbers.  If nothing else, formalizing logic and mathematical theory with axioms provides clarity to these types of contentions.

Comment: And then this allows to define more advanced techniques such as integration and differentiation for example ... for example, before the axiomatisation of limits, there were a lot of debates about the limit of the sum $1-1+1-1+1-1+ ...$